# jQuery: how do I make a collapsable tree nav?

Tags: jquery

I have headers, and each of those headers has sub items.
When I click a header, I want it to toggle viewing or showing the headers contents:

This is what I have so far:

```
$j('h2').click(function() {
if ($j(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
    $j(this).next().show();
} else {
    $j(this).next().hide();
}
});
```

And my HTML look like this:

```
<ul class="submenu">
            <li class="section"><h2>Section One</h2>
                <ul>

                    <li>text</li>


                    <li>text</li>
<li>text</li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="section"><h2>Section Two</h2>
                <ul style="display: none; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ">
<li style="">
                            text</li><li>
                            text</li><li>
                            text</li></ul>
                </li>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the way you have it, or use a slide effect using [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), like this:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
  $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5VejJ/)

Or instantly without the slide effect using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ([test here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5VejJ/1/)):

```
$('h2').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});​
```

Or a slide + fade effect using [`.toggle(speed)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ([test here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5VejJ/2/)), like this:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).next().stop(true, true).toggle("fast");
});​
```

In each case the call to [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is to prevent animation queue build-up.  This code is for most users where `$ == jQuery`, it looks like you're using [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) though so just replace `$` with `$j` like your current code has.

Comment: this is great... love that site.. except it isn't working with my copy of jquery / Jqueryui / prototype.. =\ no idea why yet.

Comment: I'm using $j but I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It's weird, cause RIGHT above your code, I use the $j thing

Comment: and then what is really baffeling, is if i type it out myself, either in the fiddle or in my app, it just doesn't work... no errors though.

(this is with the first one, with the link you posted)

Comment: @DerNalia - Are you doing this inside a `document.ready` call? Like this: `$(function() { ...the code above... });`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on this subject:

http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/ea21_turn-nested-lists-into-a-collapsible-tree-with-jquery

You will have to tweak it a bit if you want to continue to use the `<h2>` tags within the lists, but that should be trivial.

Comment: that method seems a bit complex =\